# Sorting in Entity Framework for certain parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a search results table in which their is a column that contains limited values that can be

```
"Completed", "Recruiting", "Active and not Recruiting"
```

I want "Recruiting" rows to come first and then "Active and not Recruiting" and at last "Completed".

The expression that I am using is this

```
List<Search> lst = new List<Search>(); 

var hello = db.tblSomething.Where(em=>em.someid==obj.someid).ToList

foreach(item in hello)
{
   SomeClass obj1 = new SomeClass();
   obj1.Status = hello.Status;   
   lst.Add(obj1);   
}
```

Status can contain either of three "Completed" , "Recruiting" , "Active and not Recruiting".

What will be the expression for Recruiting Status elements to come first?

Answer (score 2):

> I want "Recruiting" columns to come first and then "Active and not Recruiting" and at last "Completed".

Use [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx).

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7qYBbd).

```
    public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<SomeClass>
    {
        new SomeClass{ Status = "Recruiting"},
        new SomeClass{ Status = "Completed"},
        new SomeClass{ Status = "Active and not Recruiting"},
        new SomeClass{ Status = "Completed"},
        new SomeClass{ Status = "Recruiting"}
    };
    
    PrintList(list);
    
    Console.WriteLine("-");
    
    var sorted = list
        .OrderBy(sc => sc.Status.Equals("Recruiting", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            ? 0
            : sc.Status.Equals("Active and not Recruiting", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 ? 1
                 : sc.Status.Equals("Completed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    ? 2
                    : 3)
        .ToList();
    
    
    PrintList(sorted);

}

public static void PrintList(IEnumerable<SomeClass> list)
{
    foreach(var sc in list) Console.WriteLine(sc.Status);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Status { get; set; }  
}
```

Results:

> Recuiting
>
> Completed
>
> Active and not Recruiting
>
> Completed
>
> Recuiting
>
> -
>
> Recuiting
>
> Recuiting
>
> Active and not Recruiting
>
> Completed
>
> Completed

**That's all fine and dandy, but very ugly and really fragile code.  Instead I would highly recommend using an [Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) and [DisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pz96EC)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
                    
public class Program
{
    public enum StatusType
    {
        [Display(Name = "Invalid", Order = -1)]
        Invalid = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Recuiting", Order = 0)]
        Recruiting,
        [Display(Name = "Completed", Order = 2)]
        Completed,
        [Display(Name = "Active and not Recruiting", Order = 1)]
        ActiveAndNotRecruiting
    }
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<SomeClass>
        {
            new SomeClass{ Status = StatusType.Recruiting, Id = 1, Name = "Abraham"},
            new SomeClass{ Status = StatusType.Completed, Id = 2, Name = "Ben"},
            new SomeClass{ Status = StatusType.ActiveAndNotRecruiting, Id = 3, Name = "Carl"},
            new SomeClass{ Status = StatusType.Completed, Id = 4, Name = "Dan"},
            new SomeClass{ Status = StatusType.Recruiting, Id = 5, Name = "Erin"}
        };
        
        PrintList(list);
        
        Console.WriteLine("-");
        
        var sorted = list
            .OrderBy(cs => cs.Status.ToDisplay().Order)
            .ToList();
        
        
        PrintList(sorted);

    }

    public static void PrintList(IEnumerable<SomeClass> list)
    {
        foreach(var sc in list) Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} is {2}", sc.Id, sc.Name, sc.Status.ToDisplay().Name);
    }
    
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }  
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static DisplayAttribute ToDisplay(this Enum enumValue) 
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
            .First()
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .Where(a => a is DisplayAttribute)
            .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
    }
}
```

Results:

> 1, Abraham is Recuiting
>
> 2, Ben is Completed
>
> 3, Carl is Active and not Recruiting
>
> 4, Dan is Completed
>
> 5, Erin is Recuiting
>
> -
>
> 1, Abraham is Recuiting
>
> 5, Erin is Recuiting
>
> 3, Carl is Active and not Recruiting
>
> 2, Ben is Completed
>
> 4, Dan is Completed

The advantage to using an Enum is that the Name of the properties and sort are encapulated into a single logical location.  If you want to change the order, you can do so in a single location, making sure that everything else changes and nothing else will break.  This also removes the use of [magic numbers/strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: if i have other properties also in someclass like id or something they will also accordingly change their position as per status position or not ?

Comment: the sorted list is the object sorted by a value.  It does not change the objects, just the order in the list (I will update the examples).

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)` method. Define you comparison for `Search` as needed. See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx